# Kubernetes: Difference between NodePort in version kubernetes 1.0 & 1.1

Tags: kubernetes

I have just started with Kubernetes and I am confused about the difference between NodePort on version `release-1.0` and `release-1.1`.

I have cluster with 3 node on 3 server (10.0.5.55, 5.66. 5.57),
I run pods with replication controller and scale 2 replica like this

replcation controller:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    name: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: myproject/backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

services (use NodePort):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
  labels:
    name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    name: backend
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 10560
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30560
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

2 pods locate on 5.55 and 5.56

In version `release-1.0` I can access services in 5.57, but in `release-1.1` is not.

Pls explain my doubts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Services that use NodePort should be visible at `<NodeIP>:spec.ports[*].nodePort` and `spec.clusterIp:spec.ports[*].port`, in both release 1.0 and 1.1.